# In quasar how pass data to the layout from the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

In http://quasar-framework.org/, I have several screens that share the same layout, like lists of products and customers.

But, I don't see how I can pass the data from the page to their layout. For example, the layout has a title that I wish to change depending on which page is being displayed:

```
//Routes:
  {
    path: '/orders',
    component: () => import('layouts/list'),
    children: [
      { name: 'pickCustomer', path: '/customer', component: () => import('pages/CustomersList') },
      { name: 'pickProducts', path: '/products/:customer_id', component: () => import('pages/AddProductsList') },
      { name: 'addProduct', path: '/addproduct/:order_id/:product_id', component: () => import('pages/AddProductsList') },
      { name: 'confirmOrder', path: '/confirm/:order_id', component: () => import('pages/AddProductsList') }
    ]
  }

//list.vue
    <template>
      <q-layout>
        <q-layout-header>
            <q-toolbar>
            <q-btn
                flat
                round
                dense
                icon="chevron_left"
                @click="leftDrawer = !leftDrawer"
            />
            <q-toolbar-title>
                {{title}}
            </q-toolbar-title>
            <q-btn flat round dense icon="save" label="Add" />
            </q-toolbar>

            <q-toolbar>
            <q-toolbar-title>
                <q-search v-model="search" @input="change" inverted color="none" />
            </q-toolbar-title>
            </q-toolbar>
        </q-layout-header>          </q-layout>
    </template>

    <script>    
    export default {
      // name: 'LayoutName',
    }
    </script>

//Customers.vue
<template>
</template>

<script>
import CustomersRows from '../statics/json/customers.json'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Customers', <--HOW TO PASS THIS?
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: above code should always show first child component. how you redirect `<TNavigation >` to other component?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Also, this is short sample of the full code.

Comment: you can fork [Quasar Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/381l9rz8wm), then post your codes, we can help you from there.

Comment: Is not possible to access the page from the layout?

Comment: My thoughts are you may misunderstand how Vue router and `<route-view>` works. But you do not provide the codes on `<TNavagation>` and your home page, so can't figure out how to do.

Comment: @Sphinx I remove tnavigator and use only quasar components. Why is home necessary? Is required to have a global singleton to this to work?

Comment: sorry for my bad english, home page means the page you put your navigations. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/posva/22wgksa3/), is the similar layout/navigation you need?

Comment: @Sphinx yes is similar, now the question is how if I click in a sup-page can I change data in the layout

Comment: I would like to change the title as well based on which page is called. Maybe use a Vuex store or use the global event bus.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use meta in your routes. In your layout, use this:

```html
<q-toolbar-title
    v-if="$route.meta.title"
    class="text-center"
>
    {{ $route.meta.title }}
</q-toolbar-title>
<q-toolbar-title
    v-else 
    class="text-center"
>
    Any default title you may have
</q-toolbar-title>
```

or simply:

```html
<q-toolbar-title class="text-center">
    {{ $route.meta.title || 'Any default title you may have' }}
</q-toolbar-title>
```

This could be set up in your routes like so:

```js
[
    { path: '/', meta: { title: 'Dashboard' } },
    { path: '/route-1', meta: { title: 'Route 1' } },
]
```

Comment: Note that this route meta solution works for nested routes! Vue router will traverse up the tree until it finds a match, so the most specific title will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [portal-vue](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue) for a pretty robust solution to this problem.

In your page you would add a "portal" to your header, with the header being the "portal destination".  This allows you to modify the header from anywhere.